# How to create external redirect for below internal redirect using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

i have this rule in .htaccess file which is internal redirect can anybody tell me how to make this external redirect using R301

```
#Internal Rewrite#
RewriteRule ^(.*)page/([^/\.]+)/?$ $1?page=$2 [L]
```

I want to make it something like below [but it is not working something is wrong here..]

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?page=([0-9]+).*
RewriteRule (.*) $1/page/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule (.*)/page/1 $1 [R=301,L]
```

Any expert here can help me..Thank you in avance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `R=301` flag like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)page/([^/.]+)/?$ $1?page=$2 [L,R=301,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: `QSA` means `Query String Append` which makes sure to preserve existing query string while adding new query parameter `page=$2`. Please check: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html for all the details.

Comment: Thank you...Anubhava... one question if http://example.com/photodirectory/page/1 is there then want to redirect to http://example.com/photodirectory/ could you please help me.

Comment: For that you can use: `RewriteRule ^(photodirectory)/page/1/?$ $1 [L,R=301,NC]`